# Display months in x-axis nvd3 chart - odoo?

Tags: d3.js, charts, odoo, nvd3.js, odoo-8

I have created a line chart to display last three month data. It works fine except it only show two dates/months in x-axis (first and last). The label for middle point doesn't show.

**linechart.js**

```
self.chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .margin({left:100,botoom:50,top:0})
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
            .transitionDuration(350)
            .showYAxis(true)
            .showXAxis(true)
            .showLegend(false)
            .width(220)
            .height(150)

          self.chart.xAxis
            .axisLabel('Month')
            .tickFormat(function(d) {

               return d3.time.format("%b-%Y")(new Date(d)); })

          self.chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel(myData[0].ylabel)
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

          myData = self.data;
```

**Data**

[{'y': 7L, 'x': u'2016-10'}, {'y': 2L, 'x': u'2016-11'}, {'y': 6L, 'x': u'2016-12'}]

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `xAxis.ticks(d3.time.months)` ?

Comment: i guess, It is because of the available space. Can you increase the width of the chart and check ? `nv.models.lineChart().width(420)`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickValues

You need to set tickValues for your axis or d3 will generate them for you. Take a look at the snippet below:

```
        chart.xAxis
            .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format("%m/%d/%y")(new Date(d)); })
            .tickValues(_.map(tick_values, function(d) { return getDate(d); }))
            .rotateLabels(-30);
```

where `tick_values` is an array. For more info check the documentation above.